# How to calling this Xiaolin Wu's line algorithm from rosettacode in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to calling Xiaolin wu's line algorithm. I find a version from rosettacode.org but I don't know how to calling it.

Here is the link: 
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm#C.2B.2B

I don't understand this part

`const std::function<void(int x, int y, float brightness)>& plot`

Could you give me a example to calling this function.

Comment: `std::function` is a wrapper for functions and in your example's case its wrapping a function `void plot(int x, int y, float brightness)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just means that the last argument is a function plotting a point given the coordinates and the desired brightness.

It allows different flavors, e.g. with function pointer, or lambdas.

```
void my_plot(int x, int y, float brightness) {
  // plot things
}

int main() { 
    WuDrawLine(0, 0, 100, 256, my_plot);
    WuDrawLine(0, 100, 0, 256, [](int x, int y, float brightness) { /*do stuff*/ });
    return 0;
}
```